# How to convert a SAS dataset into CSV file whereas a single filed in it has value with comma

Tags: sas, dataset, data-analysis, sas-macro

I have a SAS dataset, let us say

it has 4 columns A,B,C,D and the values

```
A = x
B = x
C = x
**D = x,y**
```

Here column D has two values inside a single column while converting it into CSV format it generates a new column with the value Y. How to avoid this and to convert SAS dataset into CSV file?

```
 * get some test records in a file;
Data _null_;
    file 'c:\tmp\test.txt' lrecl=80;
    put '1,22,Hans Olsen,Denmark,333,4';
    put '1111,2,Turner, Alfred,England,3333,4';
    put '1,222,Horst Mayer,Germany,3,4444';
run;

* Read the file as a delimited file; 
data test; infile 'c:\tmp\test.txt' dsd dlm=',' missover;
    length v1 v2 8 v3 v4 $40 v5 v6 8;
    input
        'V1'n : ?? BEST5.
        'V2'n : ?? BEST5.
        'V3'n : $CHAR40.
        'V4'n : $CHAR40.
        'V5'n : ?? BEST5.
        'V6'n : ?? BEST5.;
run;

* Read the file and write another file.
* If 6 delimiters and not 5, change the third to #;
data test2; 
    infile 'c:\tmp\test.txt' lrecl=80 truncover;
    file 'c:\tmp\test2.txt' lrecl=80;
    length rec $80;
    drop pos len;
    input rec $char80.;
    if count(rec,',') = 6 then do;
        call scan(rec,4,pos,len,',');
        substr(rec,pos-1,1) = '','';
    end;
    put rec;
run;

* Read the new file as a delimited file; 
data test2; infile 'c:\tmp\test2.txt' dsd dlm=',' missover;
    length v1 v2 8 v3 v4 $40 v5 v6 8;
    input
        'V1'n : ?? BEST5.
        'V2'n : ?? BEST5.
        'V3'n : $CHAR40.
        'V4'n : $CHAR40.
        'V5'n : ?? BEST5.
        'V6'n : ?? BEST5.;
run;
```

In this code, it add '#' but I want ',' itself in the output.
Could anyone please guide me to do that?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have tried. Have you looked into "proc export"?

Comment: @Amir I have edited that code. Kindly check it once. I want comma inside a column value.

Comment: What are you starting with and what are you trying to generate?  Are you trying to convert a CSV file to a dataset or a dataset to a CSV file? SAS does not have problems with commas going either way.  Unless you are starting with an invalidly created CSV file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are starting with an improperly created CSV file.

```
1,22,Hans Olsen,Denmark,333,4
1111,2,Turner, Alfred,England,3333,4
1,222,Horst Mayer,Germany,3,4444
```

That should have been made like this:

```
1,22,Hans Olsen,Denmark,333,4
1111,2,"Turner, Alfred",England,3333,4
1,222,Horst Mayer,Germany,3,4444
```

If you are positive that you know that the only field with embedded commas is the third then you can use a data step to read it in and generate a valid file.

```
data _null_;
  infile bad dsd truncover ;
  file good dsd ;
  length v1-v6 dummy $200;
  input v1-v2  @;
  do i=1 to countw(_infile_,',','q')-5;
    input dummy @;
    v3=catx(', ',v3,dummy);
  end;
  input v4-v6 ;
  put v1-v6 ;
run;
```

Once you have a properly formatted CSV file then it is easy to read.

```
data want;
  infile good dsd truncover ;
  length v1-v2 8 v3-v4 $40 v5-v6 8;
  input v1-v6 ;
run;
```

But if the extra comma could be in any field then you will probably need to have a human fix those lines.

Answer (score 2):

If your field value contains the field delimiter you will want to double quote the field value.  `Proc EXPORT` will do such double quoting when the data base type is specified as `CSV`

Example:

```
data have;
A = 1;
B = 2;
C = 3;
D = 'x,y';
run;

filename csv temp;

proc export data=have outfile=csv dbms=csv;
run;

data _null_;
  infile csv;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

The log will show the exported file contains double quoted values as needed in the csv file produced.

Log

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,"x,y"
```